# Open files only opens terminal instead of file browser

Tags: command-line, nautilus, mime-type

I have a problem: For some reason, if I open a file from inside an application (such as in Firefox "Open downloaded file in folder", for example), it only opens gnome-terminal in the home directory, which isn't useful at all.

This was probably caused because I tried setting the default file browser to Dolphin instead of Nautilus. However, I don't remember what I did exactly.

I've tried looking into `/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache`:

```
inode/directory=
org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop;
org.gnome.baobab.desktop;
org.kde.dolphin.desktop;
org.kde.gwenview.desktop;
nemo.desktop;easytag.desktop;
git-cola-folder-handler.desktop;
kde4-kfmclient_dir.desktop;
```

Everything seems normal (line breaks are only for easier reading, this is all in one line). Then I tried `sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime` and rebooting - nothing. If I try to open a file in the file browser, all I get is a terminal in the home directory.

How do I reset this to the default file browser or any file browser?

Comment: Check your ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list

Comment: Hm, it says `inode/directory=kde4-dolphin.desktop`. Maybe missing an `org.`? Not sure.

Comment: Not sure as well but you can give it a try.